# Double Integral Problem - Transforming limits

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The double integral $\int_0^2\int_x^{4-x} f(x,y) dy dx $ under the transformation $ u = x+2$, $v = y- 2x$ is transformed into?

My attempt:

I used the equations $y=x$ and $y=4-x$ to get the relations $u = -2v$ and $u =4$. So I get $-2v <= u <= 4 $. But how do I get the limits of the other variable v?
I think this approach is incorrect. Any suggestions on how to attempt such a problem?

Comment: What is your idea behind the transformation $v = y-2x$?

Comment: @AlexSilva The question itself mentions this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the variables in double integration:
$$\iint \limits_{D_{x,y}} f(x,y) dxdy = \iint \limits_{D_{u,v}}f\left(T(u,v)\right)|J(u,v)|dudv,$$ where $T(u,v)$ is the representation of $(x,y)$ in coordinates $(u,v)$, $|J(u,v)|$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix on $u,v$, and $D_{x,y}$ and $D_{u,v}$ is the region of integration on variables $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$, respectively.

Hence,

$x = u-2$ and $ y = v+ 2u -4$ $\Rightarrow T(u,v) = (u-2, v+2u-4).$ Thus, the Jacobian is

\begin{equation}
J(u,v) =  \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2\\
0& 1 \\
\end{array} \right] \Rightarrow |J(u,v)| = 1.
\end{equation}

$D_{x,y} =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq x\leq 2, x \leq y \leq 4-x\}.$ The same region in coordinates $(u,v)$ is given by

$$D_{u,v} =\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2 \leq u\leq 4, -u+2 \leq v \leq -3u+10\}.$$ Then,

$$\int \limits_{0}^{2} \int \limits_{x}^{4-x} f(x,y)dydx=\int \limits_{2}^{4} \int \limits_{-u+2}^{-3u+10} f(u-2,v+2u-4)dvdu.$$

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't getting the correct limits for the new variables. I plotted the new region on the uv plane. Now the bounds make sense.